# AudioTrack playing with inconsistent speed on different devices

Tags: android, audiotrack

I am currently working with `AudioTrack`. I am loading an mp3 file and playing it. However, depending on devices, the music plays either at half the rate or normal rate.

My code:

```
AudioTrack track= new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    sampleRate,
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
    initBuffer,
    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

`sampleRate` is the sample rate return by `AudioFormat` and `initBuffer` the buffer size from `AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize()`.

I have tried to change the sample rate but no difference. Buffer size also has no impact.

In fact, switching to `CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO` does make the music play at normal rate on the devices that were slow, but it also makes the ones working fine playing at twice the normal speed. My problem is that I want all devices to play at the normal speed.

Any suggestions?

I have read this thread:[Android AudioTrack slow playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940603/android-audiotrack-slow-playback), but it doesn't tell me how to find out which devices should play in mono or stereo.

Devices at normal speed: Urbano 4.2.2, Galaxy S4 4.3

Devices at half the speed, Galaxy S4 4.2.2, Experia Z 4.2.2

BTW, I cannot use `MediaPlayer` for playback. The `AudioTrack` is included in a custom player and I need to write audio data as I extract it. `MediaPlayer` won't do the trick.

Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might benefit by subscribing to [andraudio](http://music.columbia.edu/mailman/listinfo/andraudio) and asking there.

Comment: Thanks! I will check there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. Not the best fix but it works at least.

For those who are interested, I am reading the `BufferInfo` size and based on it, decide at which playback rate I should play. Basically when playback is slow the size is twice bigger than for normal speed playback. Just a guess, but the `MediaCodec` might duplicate data for stereo configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced it when trying to decode mono file using MediaCodec. On some devices,the codec would output stereo stream while mono on other. When setting up the audio track I used media format returned by MediaExtractor, which was mono. On devices where the codec would produce stereo stream, the audio track would be fed with twice as many samples. The solution is to listen for MediaFormatChanged event from MediaCodec and adjust the MediaFormat of the AudioTrack.

Answer (score 0):

[AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) only allows PCM audio data, you cannot play mp3 wit AudioTrack directly, you have to convert your mp3 to PCM or use something else (e.g. MediaPlayer) than AudioTrack.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm already converting the file before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little tricky but here is what you can do using `adb` and `ALSA`.
Android internally uses [ALSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture).

Your device should have `ALSA`, try :

```
root@user:/$ adb shell cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.25.
```

Just take a look at [Reading ALSA Device names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Concepts).
Every **device** (subdivision of a **card**) has a **capture** and a **playback** component.

Like `/proc/asound/card0/pcm1p` and `/proc/asound/card0/pcm1p` where card is `0` device is `1`
`pcm1p` is your playback and `pcm1c` is capture (for recording).

1. **Access your device using `adb`:**

   ```
   root@user:/$ adb shell
   shell@android:/$:
   ```
2. **Identifying your device:**

   So you see `/proc/asound/pcm` will give you a long list.

   ```
   shell@android:/$: cat /proc/asound/pcm                                     
   00-00: MultiMedia1 (*) :  : playback 1 : capture 1
   00-01: MultiMedia2 (*) :  : playback 1 : capture 1
   00-02: CS-Voice (*) :  : playback 1 : capture 1
   ```

   From the above I find `00-00: MultiMedia1 (*)` as `card0` and `device0` is for Multimedia playback.
3. **Getting Playback Parameter:**

   **Play** your loaded mp3 file using your standard music player Application.
   While the song is playing.
   Issue the following commands for `card0`, `device0`(p - playback), and `subdevice0`

   ```
   shell@android:/$: cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params              
   access: RW_INTERLEAVED
   format: S16_LE
   subformat: STD
   channels: 2
   rate: 44100 (44100/1)
   period_size: 1920
   buffer_size: 3840
   ```

   So try using the same values when you call `AudioTrack track= new AudioTrack(...);`
   The above value will only be visible when the device is in *open* (Playing some audio).

   If you issue this to a wrong device (like say `pcm1p`), you will see the following:

   ```
   shell@android:/$: cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm1p/sub0/hw_params    
   closed
   ```

**Note** :
Step 1 doesn't require phone to be rooted, [How to Setup ADB](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/).

**Alternatives**:

1. Have you tried the AudioTrack APIs like [getChannelConfiguration()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getChannelConfiguration()) or [getChannelCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getChannelCount()) from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) - Just Asking.
2. Have you tried looking at the MP3 file properties, the metadata has information on the audio parameters.